# Is a mining program necessary for mining, or can bitcoind mine by itself?

Tags: mining-software

I'm having a hard time understanding the relationship between daemons (such as `bitcoind` or `litecoind`) and mining.  Some things I read make it seem that you need a separate mining app and some things seem to suggest that the daemon itself does mining.  Which is it?  I'm thinking maybe the daemon **can** do mining but it needs to be enabled and if you don't enable it you can use a separate app instead?  I'm confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The daemon can do mining using the `-gen` [command line option](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin), but it's CPU mining and is impractical nowadays.

Using a separate mining app is practical. That separate mining app connects to a running `bitcoind` via its JSON-RPC API in order to facilitate [getwork](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Getwork) or [getblocktemplate](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Getblocktemplate) requests necessary for hashing.

The JSON-RPC API is configured in `bitcoin.conf` or at the [command line](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin) using these arguments:

```
-rpcuser=<user>        Username for JSON-RPC connections
-rpcpassword=<pw>      Password for JSON-RPC connections
-rpcport=<port>        Listen for JSON-RPC connections on <port> (default: 8332 or testnet: 18332)
-rpcallowip=<ip>       Allow JSON-RPC connections from specified IP address
```

Comment: Is `-gen` impractical for **litecoin** mining?

Comment: Not yet, as far as I know. AFAIK, CPU mining is still profitable on Litecoin, but of course decreasingly so.

Comment: Note that the mining functionality was removed in Bitcoin Core 0.13.0: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/release-notes/release-notes-0.13.0.md#removal-of-internal-miner